# How do I provide real time update in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vue.js

I am working on an e-commerce site. There are times where a product would no longer be available but the user would have added it to the cart or added to their saved items. How do I implement the feature such that if the product has been updated, the user would be notified as soon as possible?

I thought about doing a cron job that would check the status of the product if it still available or has been recently updated. But I do not know if that is feasible. I am open to better ideas

Thanks

Similar images are included below
[image: something similar to this][image: and this]

Comment: You can use Server-Side Events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve falls into *real-time* updates category and technically there would be more than one option to achieve this.

The chosen solution would depend on your application architecture and requirements. Meanwhile, I can suggest looking into [*Ably*](https://github.com/ably/ably-js) SDK for *Node.js* which can offer a good starter.

Here down a sample implementation where on the back-end you will be publishing messages upon item's stock reaching its limit:

```
// create client
var client = new Ably.Realtime('your-api-key');
// get appropriate channel
var channel = client.channels.get('product');
// publish a named (may be the product type in your case) message (you can set the quantity as the message payload
channel.publish('some-product-type', 0);
```

On the subscriber side, which would be your web client, you can subscribe to messages and update your UI accordingly:

```
// create client using same API key
var client = new Ably.Realtime('your-api-key');
// get product channel
var channel = client.channels.get('product');
// subscribe to messages and update your UI
channel.subscribe(function (message) {
  const productName = message.name;
  const updatedQuantity = message.data;
  // update your UI or perform whatever action
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did a live betting app once and of course live updates are the most important part.

I suggest taking a look into websockets. The idea is pretty straight forward. On backend you emit an event let's say `itemGotDisabled` and on frontend you just connect to your websocket and listen to events.

You can create a custom component that will handle the logic related to webscoket events in order to have a cleaner and more organized code an you can do any type of logic you want to updated to component as easy as `yourFEWebsocketInstance.onmessage = (event) => {}`.

Of course it's not the only way and I am sure there are packages that implements this in an even more easy to understand and straight forward way.